# Mongoose returns null from query

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Why does this return undefined when I know the ID is correct?

```js
const user = await Users.findOne({ _id })
console.log(user)
```

Comment: you can try it like this: `const user = await Users.findById(_id);`

Comment: @Ifaruki I did but it didn't work either :(

Comment: mongoose version ?